# Can numpy.isin() be vectorized to compare lists of lists?

Tags: python, numpy, isin

Suppose you have two lists of equal length, made of lists of int.

```
y_hat = np.array([[0,1,2,6], [1,2,3,5]])
y_pred = np.array([[0, 3], [0, 4]])
```

You want to compare every list of y_pred to the equivalent (same index) list in y_hat and return a list of bool if the ith element of y_pred is in y_hat:

```
result = np.array([[True, False], [False, False]]) # same shape of y_pred
```

You cannot use np.isin(), since it would return:

```
result = np.isin(y_pred, y_hat)
# np.array([[True, True], [True, False]])
```

Is there a vectorized .isin() function to avoid a for loop?

```
### Slow for loop
result = []
for y_h, y_p in zip(y_hat, y_pred):
   result_one = np.isin(y_p, y_h)
   result.append(result_one)
```

Comment: Those are not lists of lists, those are numpy arrays

Comment: You’re right, but you don’t answer the question

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `np.isin` can't be used in a simple way. But you could try to scan all the values manually:

```
y_hat = np.array([[0,1,2,6], [1,2,3,5], [9,9,8,7]])
y_pred = np.array([[0,3], [0,4], [8,7]])
isin_vals = np.equal(y_hat[:, None], y_pred[:, :, None])

isin_vals
>>> array([[[ True, False, False, False],
            [False, False, False, False]],

           [[False, False, False, False],
            [False, False, False, False]],

           [[False, False,  True, False],
            [False, False, False,  True]]])

np.any(isin_vals, axis=2)
>>> array([[ True, False],
           [False, False],
           [ True,  True]])
```

Not sure if it's powerful as much as `np.isin` could do in 1D.

Comment: Clever solution! Thx